# Selectively toggling <DIV> in browser's viewport

Tags: ios, css, html, viewport

I'm writing an `HTML5` app for `iOS`.
After going through [this](http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5) article, I thought of doing some performance optimisation
by keeping some HTML nodes in `DOM` but not keeping them in `viewport`.
For the demo purpose, I have been using following code (my actual work scenario is going to have a lot more `<div>`)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function func(){
        var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
        div1.style.cssFloat = "";
        div1.style.visibility = "hidden";
        div1.style.left = "-100%";

        div2.style.left = "100%";
        div2.style.visibility = "";
        div2.style.cssFloat = "left";
    }

    function func1(){
        var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
        var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
        div2.style.cssFloat = "";
        div2.style.visibility = "hidden";
        div2.style.left = "-100%";

        div1.style.left = "100%";
        div1.style.visibility = "";
        div1.style.cssFloat = "left";
    }
</script>
</head> 
<body style="position:absolute;height: 100%;width:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;">
   <div onclick="func();" id="div1" style="background-color:blue;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:100%;display: inline;float:left;margin: 0px;padding: 0px">
   </div>
   <div onclick="func1();" id="div2" style="background-color:green;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:-100%;visibility:hidden;display: inline;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, whenever I want to show a `<div>` in `viewport` and hide all other `<div>`, I have to make the former `div's float:left` alongwith the obvious adjustments in `left(css)`
If I put `float:left` in all the `<div>`, the logic does not work and I'm not able to show the specific `<div>` which I want to show in `viewport`.
I m also unsure how `visibility:hidden` helps in performance optimisation. My guess is that, the browser doesn't repaint the `DOM` element whose `visibility(css)` is set to `hidden`. Is it the reason for better performance ?

Answer (score 2):

In a css if u give the `visiblity:hidden` means its hide the content only not that place which is occupied . if you use `disply:none` means its hide the content and place.

and repalce this in your code..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageBodyLoad(){  // this function is called at the body load.. 
            var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
            var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
            div1.style.display = "block";  // its shows div1
            div2.style.display = "none";   // its hide div2
    }
    function func(){
            var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
            var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
            div1.style.display = "none";  // its hide div1
            div2.style.display = "block"; // its shows div2
        }

        function func1(){
            var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
            var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
            div1.style.display = "block";  // its shows div1
            div2.style.display = "none";   // its hide div2
        }
    </script>
    <body style="position:absolute;height: 100%;width:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;" onload="pageBodyLoad()">`
        <div onclick="func();" id="div1" style="background-color:blue;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;float:left;margin: 0px;padding: 0px">
        </div>
        <div onclick="func1();" id="div2" style="background-color:green;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;margin: 0px;padding: 0px;">
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I m also unsure how visibility:hidden helps in performance optimisation. My guess is that, the browser doesn't repaint the DOM element whose visibility(css) is set to hidden.

I doubt that – because the layout *space* for elements set to `visibility:hidden` still gets reserved, and for that, the element dimensions have to be known. And for that, the element and all of its descendants have to be rendered.

`display:none` however does cause an element and its descendants not to be rendered at all. By definition an element with this style behaves as if it was not part of the DOM at that moment at all (from the rendering perspective).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. In that article which I have included as a link in my question, in section `Technique #2: hiding pages` last sentence,it claims that the browser does not repaint the invisible DOM element.So may be that is making peformance optimisation?